# Replace text in quotes with Regex or AWK

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a CSV file like this:

```
Name,Age,Pos,Country
John,23,GK,Spain
Jack,30,"LM, MC, ST",Brazil
Luke,21,"CMD, CD",England
```

And I need to get this:

```
Name,Age,Pos,Country
John,23,GK,Spain
Jack,30,LM,Brazil
Luke,21,CMD,England
```

With this expression I can extract the field but I don't know how to update it in the dataset

```
grep -o '\(".*"\)' file.csv | cut -d "," -f | sed 's/"//'
```

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to add their efforts which they put in order to solve their own problems, so please do add the same and let us know(not my down-vote BTW).

Comment: You are right, I forgot to show it, sorry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sed -E 's/"([^,]+)[^"]*"/\1/' ip.txt
John,23,GK,Spain
Jack,30,LM,Brazil
Luke,21,CMD,England
```

- `-E` to enable ERE
- `"` match double quote
- `([^,]+)` match non-comma characters and capture it for reuse in replacement section
- `[^"]*"` any other remaining characters
- `\1` will refer to the text that was captured with `([^,]+)`

Note that this will work only one double quoted field and won't work if there are other valid csv formats like escaped double quotes, newline character in field, etc

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, this should cover case when you have more than 1 occurrence of `"....."` in your Input_file, written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v FPAT='[^"]*|"[^"]+"' '
BEGIN{
  OFS=""
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/^".*"$/){
      gsub(/^"|"$|[, ].*/,"",$i)
    }
  }
}
1
'  Input_file
```